# Why shouldn't we talk about sensitive topics?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

In my expierence, the bad-rated questions I've posted are only those, what consider for someone maybe touchy topics.

Here are some examples:

https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/42201/what-are-some-of-the-problems-of-the-mixing-of-human-ethnical-groups

Removed question: What were the official (medical) reasons to cross homosexuality out of the official list of diseases?

Removed question on History: Had religion developed more times independantly?

I think this is totally wrong for society where everyone can freely ask and get a reasonable answer. Why shouldn't we talk about it?

Comment: I can't view your deleted questions (and most people here won't be able to) but for instance is that first one really a biology question or more sociology? Judging from the title it might have been a pretty broad question either way. Not sure where you posted the others but they don't seem directly biology related either.

Comment: Sorry, I should have tell they have been "removed". But the off-topicness didn't come to my mind.

Comment: Sensitive topics *can* be addressed on stack exchange, but they must be addressed sensitively. "Are the differences between ethnical group' genom big enough to cause some problems"? is hardly sensitive, and there are problems with the question as I've just mentioned in the biology chat room.

Comment: Honestly, it's not that some of your questions discuss "sensitive" topics, it's that a great many of your questions are just not very good. They lack research or critical thought about why something might be the way it is. They are frequently opinion-based, unclear, and/or too broad, which is the overwhelmingly main reason why they are not accepted very well.

Comment: As a side note, if you're going to post a meta question about why specific questions aren't being received well, it would be extraordinarily helpful if you could give **accessible** examples, i.e. ones that haven't been deleted or are only available for viewing by 10k+ users. Asking a question about a topic that no one can research is not very helpful.

Comment: "ethnical group", just as "race" has no meaningful biological definition (see other questions about the topic on Biology.SE). So that question is essentially not answerable from a biological point.

Comment: As for the homosexuality question, at least something similar was asked on Health.SE https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/1991/in-which-version-of-the-icd-was-homosexuality-classified-as-a-disease the question just plain doesn't seem to be on-topic on Biology for me.

Comment: Because autistic people are very sensitive

Answer (score 12):

It depends on the question. Questions need to be *answerable* not just discussion topics or requests for examples of things happening (as most of the ones you listed would be).

If a question can be correctly answered - at least in theory - then it shouldn't matter if it is controversial. But if the question can't be correctly answered, or if it's a discussion topic, or a very broad question then it likely wouldn't fit the site, regardless of the sensitivity of subject matter.

Comment: Do you want to say it doesn't matter anyway?

Comment: That's not the point

Answer (score 5):

Following on from Jon's point, those 3 questions do not appear to be good questions (from the perspective of answerability)

They are ones I would vote to close, not from any sensitivity perspective, but because:

- problems of mixing of ethnic groups: who decides? are there problems - this seems opposite to what I see (opinion)?
- official medical reasons: where? When?
- has religion developed independently: we have extensive proof that religions have developed throughout known human history. Why would this be a question?

And they are worded in a way that would require improvement anyway.

Comment: 1. Question is, wheter diseases caused by non-ideal gene mixing of two different people's race exist. A disease is something that decreases your life function or your evolutionary fitness - totally objective.

Comment: 2. Official reasons of the World medical assosiation what declared to cross it out in 1999.

Comment: 3. Of course it had developed. Question is, wheter it had developed more times independantly, or if it shares a common origine.

Comment: 1- can't see your deleted question, but I would class that as mostly subjective. 2- if they have published, then use that. If not, then speculation. 3- that makes no sense to me. More times independently than what?

Comment: 1. How could be this type of disease more subjective than any else? 2. There was more discussion in the question, but I admit Is should have done more research about that (even I don't think I'd understand it) 3. more than once

Comment: 1 - what do you mean "type of disease" - this shows a preconception that could well be entirely wrong

Comment: 3 - we know religions have developed many times, in many eras. Not sure what you mean, still...

Comment: 1- This would be a type of disease such as inherited, contagious or adaptive.

Comment: Waaaaaaay too broad, then

Comment: 3 - Oh yes, they had developed for many times. But do they share "one common ancestor"?

Comment: Well, question isn't how would this type of disease play role or anything such like that, only if it does exist...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/983/discussion-between-rory-alsop-and-probably).